# Imagem aparece uma borda branca embaixo

Tags: html5, css3

Galera, eu fiz um `button` e dentro deste `button`, eu coloquei uma img. No site, a imagem fica com uma borda branca embaixo. Já tirei a borda do botão pelo CSS e mesmo assim ela continua. Qual propriedade será que está dando a borda? Quero retirá-la.

**Obs:** ela só aparece embaixo.

**Código HTML:**

```
<article id="almoco">
<header class="categoria">Almoço</header>
<figure>
<button>
```

**CSS da imagem:**

```
  img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

**CSS do button:**

```
  button {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, compartilhe seu código para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Falta o código CSS relacionado e o HTML do botão

Comment: Código HTML:
<article id="almoco">
   <header class="categoria">Almoço</header>
   <figure>
     <button><a href="ctg/almoco.php"><img class="redonda" src="img/almoco.png" alt ="almoco" title="ALMOÇO"></a></button>
   </figure>
  </article>

CSS da imagem: 
img {
  max-width: 100%;
 }

      CSS do button: 
button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-style: none;
 }

Comment: Use `padding: 0` no botão.